# flutter ontap is calling the entire widget code

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an image hidden under a matrix of pixels as shown below.

[image]

once you click on any color, it should turn transparent. Therefore, clicking on every pixel would reveal the image hidden underneath it as shown below. The code to achieve this is below.

[image]

```
  getAlmostRandomMatrix(size) {
    makeMatrix() => Iterable<List<Color>>.generate(
        size, (i) => List<Color>.filled(size, Colors.transparent)).toList();
    List<List<Color>> matrix = makeMatrix(); //size x size matrix with transparent colors as default
    int frequency = (size * size / 3)
        .toInt(); // this assumes that the size is a multiple of 3
    // else it will cause unequal distribution in the matrix
    List<int> distribution = [
      frequency,
      frequency,
      frequency
    ]; //this assumes that team size is 3

    Random random = Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        int rand = random.nextInt(3);
        if (distribution[rand] > 0) {
          switch (rand) {
            case 0:
              matrix[i][j] = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;
              break;
            case 1:
              matrix[i][j] = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary;
              break;
            case 2:
              matrix[i][j] = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error;
              break;
            default:
              matrix[i][j] = Colors.transparent;
          }
          // matrix[i][j] = rand;
          distribution[rand] -= 1;
        } else {
          // brute force assignment to force equal frequency distribution
          // these colors won't be random anymore
          if (distribution[0] > 0) {
            matrix[i][j] = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;
            distribution[0] -= 1;
          } else if (distribution[1] > 0) {
            matrix[i][j] = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary;
            distribution[1] -= 1;
          } else {
            matrix[i][j] = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error;
            distribution[2] -= 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return matrix;
  }

  Widget paintPixelsOnReward() {
    int size = 9;
    List<List<Color>> matrix = getAlmostRandomMatrix(size);
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          const Image(
            width: 360,
            height: 315,
            image: AssetImage('lib/assets/images/orange_butterfly_image.png'),
          ),
          Column(children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
              Row(
                children: [
                  for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) ...[
                    LayoutBuilder(
                      builder: (context, constraints) {
                        return Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                // print(matrix);
                                setState(() {
                                  matrix[i][j] = Colors.transparent;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: 40,
                                height: 35,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: matrix[i][j],
                                    border: Border.all(
                                        width: 1, color: Colors.white)),
                              )),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ]
                ],
              )
          ]),
        ]));
  }
```

However, calling `onTap` is not working as expected. On tapping a particular color element, instead of it being turned transparent, all the pixels are randomized again. It seems like `getAlmostRandomMatrix(size)` is being called again on tapping. is there a way to avoid that?

I have tried putting the matrix as a class level variable but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

There's most likely a problem with your state-management. If you are using setState(), depending on your code (which is not contained in this snippet) the getAlmostRandomMatrix() might be called. Just use a debugger to determine if so.

Are you calling getAlmostRandomMatrix() only if the widget is built for the first time? My guess is, this method is called every setState. Reasons might be a call within build() or something similar.